# How to add an additional field in Django model form

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I am trying to include some dummy fields in my model form and using the same in model formset factory.

## Model form:

```
class DistForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dist_from_txt = forms.CharField()
    ...
    class Meta:
        model: Distance
        fields = ('dist_from', 'dist_to', 'distance')
        widgets = {
    ...
    }
```

However, when rendered the extra field does not show up on the form.

Needlessly to mention here that I have searched (including [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset)) and failed to find a possible solution.

**Question is: How to correctly add and render extra field/s in model form?**

Comment: forms.TextInput is a widget instance, not a form field instance. Use CharField.

Comment: @nigel222 post that as an answer please.

Answer (score 3):

forms.TextInput is a widget instance, not a form field instance. Use CharField:

```
class DistForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dist_from_txt = forms.CharField()
...
    class Meta:
        model: Distance
        fields = ('dist_from', 'dist_to', 'distance')
        widgets = {
...
```